# How do you retrieve the result with the higher percentage from image classification and write the result in a txt file?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification

I am currently using tensorflow to do image classification classifying tooth images between "Healthy" and "Decayed" tooths.

This is the current code:

```
import tensorflow as tf, sys

image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
               in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

# Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

for node_id in top_k:
    human_string = label_lines[node_id]
    score = predictions[0][node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

#Write results into text file
text_file = open("results.txt","w")
```

This is the results on CMD from one of my healthy tooth image:
healthy (score = 0.99011)
decayed (score = 0.00989)

How do I only store "healthy" or "decayed" results to results.txt as I wanna read it from a website. For example, if the score of healthy is above a certain decimal and more than decayed it will be stored as healthy.
I have tried using if statements and I couldn't figure it out.

Please help !
Thanks in advance